# Integral equations

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, integral-equations

Why Mathehtica could not solve the simple equation
$$\text{DSolve}\left[-\int_0^x t^4 (t-x)^4 y(t) \, dt-\frac{313 x^4}{15120}+\frac{115 x^2}{252}+\left(\frac{13 x^4}{15120}+\frac{11 x^2}{252}+1\right) \cos (x)-1=0,y(x),x\right]$$
Mathematica it is capable to solve  other more difficult  equation why fail in this simple case thanks it is possible get a solution derivating 
thanks

Comment: `DSolve[]`'s support for integral equations is still somewhat limited, so don't be surprised if some things don't work yet.

Comment: Thanks Mariusz Iwaniuk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eq = Inactivate[-Integrate[t^4*(t - x)^4*y[t], {t, 0, x}] - 
313*x^4/15120 + 115*x^2/252 + (13*x^4/15120 + 11 x^2/252 + 1)*Cos[x] - 1 == 0, Integrate]
```

Differentiate five times the `eq` give a solution:

```
sol = First@Solve[D[Activate@eq, {x, 5}], y[x]] // Expand
```

> $\left\{y(x)\to -\frac{29 \sin (x)}{3024 x^4}+\frac{29 \cos (x)}{3024 x^3}+\frac{5 \sin (x)}{2016 x^2}-\frac{13 \sin (x)}{362880}+\frac{13 \cos (x)}{18144
>    x}\right\}$

and check if everything is fine:

```
Activate@eq /. y[t] -> (y[x] /. sol[[1]] /. x -> t) // FullSimplify

(* True *)
```